# Issues with dropdown causing error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dropdownbox

I have drop down box that does not keep the selected value so i had to add this line of code:

```
ddl_Answer.Items.FindByValue((e.Row.FindControl("lblAns") as Label).Text).Selected = true;
```

But adding this line of code is causing me another problem.  I have built the dropdown in a Gridview and the Gridview has an Edit link, once you click the edit then you should see the drop down box, but the issue now is when i click the Edit link and nothing has been selected in the dropdown then i get an error.  It only works when something was already selected. Here is my code:

```
protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && GridView1.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
        {
            int current_quest_sk = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value);

            DropDownList ddl_Answer = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddl_Answer");
            String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select distinct DD_ANSWER from MainTable D, SecondryTable Q where Q.ANS_OPT = D.ID and  QUEST_SK= '" + current_quest_sk + "' ");

            cmd1.Connection = con2;
            con2.Open();
            ddl_Answer.DataSource = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            ddl_Answer.DataTextField = "DD_ANSWER";
            ddl_Answer.DataValueField = "DD_ANSWER";
            ddl_Answer.DataBind();
            con2.Close();
            ddl_Answer.Items.FindByValue((e.Row.FindControl("lblAns") as Label).Text).Selected = true;
}
```

here is the markup for the dropdown

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="870px" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#C2D69B"
                    HeaderStyle-BackColor="green" AllowPaging="True" ShowFooter="True" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging"
                    OnRowEditing="EditGridView1" OnRowUpdating="UpdateGridView1" OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEdit"
                    CellPadding="4" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" 
                    BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px"
                    DataKeyNames="QUEST_SK">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#C2D69B" />
                    <Columns>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblAns" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DDL_ANS")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblAns" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DDL_ANS")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Answer" runat="server">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                         <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" >
                        <ItemStyle Font-Size="Smaller" ForeColor="#FF3300" />
                        </asp:CommandField>
                    </Columns>
```

Comment: try adding ddl_Answer.selectedindex = -1 before doing find by value

Comment: Probably items collection is NULL, Maybe you tried to read that after Post Back.

Comment: `ddl_Answer.Items.FindByValue((e.Row.FindControl("lblAns") as Label).Text)` returns NULL if nothing has selected.

Comment: Is your DropdownList inside GridView, then show the Markup of the same also

Comment: thanks guys but i am still having the issue but i think i understand what is going on but can't resolve it. 
the problem is i am using RowDataBound in my gridview and when the page loads the current row index is not selected yet, i am only selecteting the current row index when i click the Edit link and it shows my drop down.  How can i call the OnRowDataBound when i click the Edit link in my gridview?

Comment: i also added the markup for the drop down